# Como puedo capturar el texto de autocompleteview en android

Tags: android-studio

**ESTE ES EL  código PARA OBTENER LOS cedulas POR AUTOCOMPlETAR A LA HORA DE INGRESAR CÉDULA
necesitaría obtener la cédula ingresada p, para evitarla como parámetro para crear el acta **

```
  public void ConsumirBeneficiarios() {
        String URL = ("http://actasentrega.colom.org/api/beneficiario");
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {//VALIDAMOS QUE EL RESPONSE contiene el token
                if (response.length() > 0) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            String muni = jsonObject1.getString("num_documento");
                            listarDocumentoExistente.add(muni);
                        }
                        AutoCompleteTextView ediText =  findViewById(R.id.autoComplete);
                        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(RegistroActa.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listarDocumentoExistente);
                        ediText.setAdapter(adapter);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }
```

**ESTE ES EL CÓDIGO PARA AGREGAR UN ACTA A LA CÉDULA AUTO-COMPLETAR- EL ERROR QUE TENGO AL INSERTAR LOS PARÁMETROS ME MUESTRA QUE EL DOCUMENTO DE CAMPO ES OBLIGATORIO, COMO SI ENVÍARA UN CAMPO VACÍO, SI ALGUIEN PUEDE AYUDARME , TE LO AGRADEZCO.**

```
 public void AgragarActa(View view) {
        String URL = ("http://actasentrega.colom.org/api/acta_entrega");
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {//VALIDAMOS QUE EL RESPONSE contiene el token
                if (!response.contains("null") && (response.contains("200"))){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"REGISTRADO DE ACTA SATISFACTORIO",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"NO SE PUDO REALIZAR EL REGISTRO",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(RegistroActa.this, "error occurrido", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                error.printStackTrace();

            }
        })

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> parametros = new HashMap<String, String>();
                parametros.put("beneficiario_id",autoCompleteTextView.getText().toString());
                parametros.put("fecha_entrega", campoFecha.getText().toString());
                parametros.put("proceso_apoyado", campoPrecesoApoyado.getText().toString());
                parametros.put("proyecto_id", comboPROYECTO.getSelectedItem().toString());
                parametros.put("lugares_entrega", campoLugarEntrega.getText().toString());
                parametros.put("vereda_corregimiento", campoVereda.getText().toString());
                parametros.put("municipio_id", comboMunicipios.getSelectedItem().toString());
                parametros.put("poblacion_id", comboPOBLACION.getSelectedItem().toString());
                parametros.put("contratista_operador", campoContratista.getText().toString());
                parametros.put("unidad_productiva", campoProductiva.getText().toString());
                return parametros;

            }
```

Comment: autocompleteview te da textos de sugerencia, cuando lo seleccionas se muestra en la vista, podrías describir como lo deseas capturar? que realizarías con esta captura?

Comment: Buenas tardes es que estoy tratando de insertar unos parametros que consumi como Documento,municipio etc..

Comment: pero a la hora de insertar los parametros me manda el siguiente error status 400,  {"errors":{"proyecto_id":["El campo Proyecto seleccionado no existe."],"fecha_entrega":["El campo Fecha entrega no corresponde con el formato de fecha Y-m-d."],"municipio_id":["El campo Municipio seleccionado no existe."],"poblacion_id":["El campo Poblaci\u00f3n seleccionado no existe."]},"message":"Verifique los campos","status":400,"data":null}

Comment: antes me desia que el campo documento era obligatorio pero ya no me muestra el mensaje si no con los parametros que te acabe de enviar

Comment: El error status 400 no tiene que ver con el titulo de tu pregunta, recuerda revisar [ask] y edita tu pregunta, te comento que el error 400 puede tener varias causas pero la común se debe a una petición incorrecta, probablemente le envias valores incorrectos.

Comment: si tienes razón lo tendré en cuenta si era que estaba obteniendo los nombres de los pero necesitaba los id de cada uno. Me puedes ayudar como hago para 
 Llenar un Spinner con Volley y obtener un id  pero que solo me muestre los nombre te agradezco muy amable.